# Different ways to display title

Tags: theme-development, permalinks

I'm new to WordPress and I'm still learning from tutorials, but I'm confused with their conflicted ways. What the difference between these two ways to make the title a link:

```
<h1>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
</h1>
```

and

```
<?php the_title(sprintf(
            '<h1><a href="%s">',
            esc_url(get_permalink())),
            '</a></h1>');
?>
```

Is it a performance issue? or a security? or what?

thanks.

**Edit:**

I know that the function `the_permalink()` has embedded `esc_url` functionality while `get_permalink` doesn't. So in my case, is there still any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second form can be handy too:

- We can also use the [third](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) parameter:

  ```
  the_title( $before, $after, $echo );
  ```

  to assign the title to a variable.

  Here's an example:

  ```
  $title = the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>', false );
  ```
- This can also help reducing the use of `<?php ?>` delimiters.

  Here's an [example](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d4d8ae24222b44e80740ea0b05370089cee2d5ba/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/content.php#L21-L25) from the *Twenty Fifteen* theme

  ```
   if ( is_single() ) :
       the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
   else :
       the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' );
   endif;
  ```

  but there are of course various ways to get rid of such if/else parts.

  Here's an alternative form for comparison:

  ```
  <?php if( is_single() ) : ?>
      <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  <?php else : ?>
      <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
  ```

Comment: please, can you explain your idea more ? .... please use full code example as mine. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Going with the first set of code that you provided:

```
<h1>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
</h1>
```

Simply put, it's much cleaner and simpler to use. As you already mentioned, `the_permalink()` already covers the `esc_url()` functionality, So why do you need to write more code when one of the functions take care of it? Less is more in this case.

Comment: Is it really matters if I open php tag twice `in first case` or once `in second case` ?

Comment: In this case, yes. Since after you finish the first PHP tag, you add `">` at the end of it since you are closing off the `<a>` (link) tag.

Comment: what is the bad about opening php tag twice for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do most things in WordPress. Either that, or there are no ways at all.

Your first example makes more sense. The second seems unnecessarily complex for no benefit.

Comment: Seconding vancoder. `sprintf()` and `printf()` are used frequently in WordPress to ensure that strings can be translated through [localization](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) functions, but that's not the case here. It's just two different ways to do the same thing.